# Different p-values for normal regression and interaction terms

Tags: r, regression, interaction

while performing a logistic regression for two variables I also wanted to perform an interaction analysis.
Particularly, I was looking to the use of a diagnostic test over time (before and after a certain period, a binary variable) and deepending on age (elderly >75 y.o. ore younger individuals, still a binary variable).
However, the p-values given in the interaction analysis for the single components are different than the original given by the single analysis, so I would like to understand what are the actual p-values reported in the interaction analysis.

Here the codes and results:

```
summary(glm(DB$Test~ DB$Time,family = binomial(link="logit"))
```

p-Value
1.52e-06

```
summary(glm(DB$Test~ DB$Age, family = binomial(link="logit"))
```

p-Value
5.4e-09

```
summary(glm(DB$Test~ DB$Time* DB$Age,family = binomial(link="logit"))
```

p-Values:

Time= 7.67e-06

Age= 0.0491

Time:Age= 0.6922

So, where does this 0.049 come from? what is it testing?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: I find it surprising that you seem to believe that including additional terms in a regression model has no impact on the other terms. All the p-values are from a test with the null hypothesis that the parameter is zero.

Comment: The principle is that if you ask a different question, the answer is likely to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you modify your model by adding or removing predictors, whether main effects or interactions, the coefficient estimates, standard errors and (therefore) $p$ values of all the terms already in the model will change. (Except for *very* exceptional circumstances.) What you are seeing is thus not surprising.

The tests you are seeing (probably, since you don't specify what exactly you are asking about) perform two-sided tests against the null hypothesis that the relevant coefficient is zero - in the context of the current model. Thus, between different models that all include a given predictor, the context changes, so the test result also changes, see above.

Comment: Ummm yes, I understand thath the model is different, but I thought that the output of R was giving the single regression analysis (as done with the "simple" model) and then the interaction analysis, that's what I was questioning: instead they actually are the B parameter of the other model.

Comment: R *is* giving the output of the two analyses. It's just that they are two *different* analyses, so the p values of predictors that are present in both analyses will differ, because the coefficient estimates are different.